# Drop-Down Menu - Python GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm trying to create a drop down menu in Python that allows me to select a set list of items(ex. mL, L, m^3) and in the same button as the drop down menu, display the chosen item in the list.  I've gotten this far but I'm stuck:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter

Avol_units = Menubutton(root, text="Units", relief=RAISED)
Avol_units.grid(row=4, column=2)
Avol_units.menu = Menu(Avol_units, tearoff = 0)
Avol_units["menu"] = Avol_units.menu

LVar  = IntVar()
mLVar = IntVar()

Avol_units.menu.add_checkbutton(label="L",
                      variable=LVar)
Avol_units.menu.add_checkbutton(label="mL",
                      variable=mLVar)
```

Comment: missing code, such as what is root. Also missing some important info. Python 2.7 or 3.3? (i guess 2.7 since Tkinter is capitalized. Please provide a ready-to-run example so i can test possible solutions without creating conflictive code with yours.

Comment: you shouldn't import Tkinter twice, not needed!

Comment: Yes, this is python 2.7, and I would suggest you look up thenewboston tkinter tutorials on youtube. That has the answer to your question. And I realise this is an old question, but they're good to watch anyway to further your knowledge, and the fact that they are done with python 3 shouldn't be too great a barrier as it uses tkinter in a very similar fashion to 2.7.

Answer (score -1):

This is all you need to implement. I have tested it and it works fine but you may have to edit some lines or correct indentations.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import tkinter.messagebox

Avol_units = Menubutton(root, text="Units", relief=RAISED)

LVar  = IntVar()
mLVar = IntVar()


Avol_units =Label(ABC2,font=("arial",12,"bold"),text="Nationality:",padx=2,pady=2,fg="Cornsilk",bg="cadet blue")
        Avol_units .grid(row=7,column=0, sticky =W)
        Avol_units =ttk.Combobox(ABC2,textvariable= Nationality, state="readonly", font=("arial",12,'bold'),
                                width=18)
        Avol_units["value"]=('','British','Nigeria','Jordan','Palastine','morocco','France','Norway')
        Avol_units.current(0)
        Avol_units.grid(row=7,column=1,pady=3, padx=20)
```

Comment: yeh also emm you might have to move things around  bit sorry with the way of the layout

Comment: Instead of provides additional information in a comment, add it to your post. Always use a code bracket to display code.